# webapi 2.0 cross origin behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, cors

i am using default webapi `ApplicationOAuthProvider` code below to login. and i add in

```
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

in the web.config and client is able to login via www.testapi.com/token.
everything works fine.

But when i create a custom webapi function. it is still asking me for access-origin control to enable. So i do so by adding this line of code in `WebapiConfig.cs`

```
 EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.myweb.com:82", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

this time it prompt error saying

> ''Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://www.myweb.com:82, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.myweb.com:82' is therefore not allowed access.

so i remove the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` in the web.config and it works!!.

i return to the login and it is asking for `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` to be added. but if i add this in. my webapi method will not be able to call.

if i dont add. client will not be able to log in.

is there a way for both to work?
below is the response of 200 with error.
[image]

**Update 1**
**startup.auth.cs**

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);//as instructed
```

**webapiconfig.cs**

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));
        //var jsonp = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        //config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this in your Api Controller `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-My-Header")]  ` This is controller level. You can add the same in a particular action method to enable cores.

Comment: it is still showing the same error "only one is allowed. i did not remove the access-origin in the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok finally i managed to get it work with help from "@manprit Singh Sahota"

i remove all the access policy from web.config.
and also the line below in `WebApiConfig`

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

i only add this line to the `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);//working line
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` nuget package
2. Install `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` nuget package
3. Add `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));` to the above of `WebApiConfig.Register(config);` line at `Startup.cs` file.
4. Add `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` to the `Startup.Auth.cs` file. This must be done prior to calling `IAppBuilder.UseWebApi`

Comment: still the same error. i also tried with trial and error by removing the access policy at web.config. still the same. haizz. this is bugging me like crazy. only 1 work at at time