# .NET Core 2.0 - Still seeing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm at wit's end on this one. I've already researched other answers to similar questions on SO w/o any luck.

I'm fairly certain I've got CORS enabled correctly to allow incoming requests (in this case, POST requests) from all origins, but I'm seeing the error below:

> Failed to load http://localhost:5000/expenses: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Here's how I've enabled CORS in my webAPI project:

**relevant methods in Startup.cs**

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ExpensesDbContext>(options =>
                                                    options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<IBaseDa<Accounts>, AccountsDataAccess>();
            services.AddTransient<IExpensesDa, ExpensesDa>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            env.EnvironmentName = "Development";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

If i'm using `.AllowAnyOrigin()` and `.AllowAnyMethod()`, why am I seeing the error above?

Comment: Have you looked at the asp.net core 2.0 answer [in this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303224/5402620)

Comment: @JonathonChase yes, I did try defining my policy and giving it a name, etc. didn’t work for me; saw the same error

Comment: @mjwills the front end that is leveraging this api is behind port 4200. I tried `.WithOrigin(“http://localhost:4200”`. Didn’t work :(

Comment: It looks like HTTP status code 500 could be the issue here - what does [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) show the response as?

Comment: are you using chrome by any chance?

Comment: @MohamoudMohamed yes, I’m using chrome

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 500.* - Fix the error first, so the server does not respond with a 500. You might just find that it works when the server doesn't error out.

Comment: See my post here . Look at my own “answer” https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669380/7339254

Answer (score 11):

Was scratching my head on this situation here for a while. I had CORS enabled properly, but some calls were still returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I found the problem... the sneaky sneaky problem...

Our problem was caused by how we were using `app.UseExceptionHandler`. Specifically, here's the code we were using, except our original code didn't have the `context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` line.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var exception = errorFeature.Error;

        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = R.ErrorUnexpected,
            Status = status,
            Detail =
              $"{exception.Message} {exception.InnerException?.Message}"
        };

        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        context.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.GetValueOrDefault();
        context.Response.WriteJson(problemDetails, "application/problem+json");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

`app.UseExceptionHandler` is a much lower level function than controller actions, and thus does not take part in anything related to CORS natively. Adding `context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` fixed the problem.

Comment: This helped me debug my problem which is basically just saying the same error mentioned on your title. Thanks a lot

Comment: This should be marked as a valid answer, took me a couple of hours to find the solution. The most irritating thing was that valid requests were returned in a proper way.

Answer (score 3):

The combination of netCore2.0 (http://localhost:5000/) + Angular (http://localhost:4200)   + chrome = Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I have had this issue before and it took me 3 days to realize that chrome will always throw this error. I think it is because chrome views localhost as the origin disregarding the port even tho the middleware explicitly tells it not too especially on POST requests.

I would try and define a policy in your startup.cs Configure services:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
  //add cors service
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));
```

then in your Configure method I would add that:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //authentication added 
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCors("Cors");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

... This most likely wont work and but try it any who.... This drove me mad and I needed the satisfaction of seeing if the request even attempted to hit the asp.netCore backend:
I used

If you really want to see I would clear your cache and cookies then add 
IHttpContextAccessor to get low level control of whats going on in the request.
In my dilema with the same problem I needed angular to send an image. I was getting the annyoing
Origin error then through exprimenting I got the Image by injecting IHttpContextAccessor into my controller and

### debugging

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //add cors service
                services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                    }));

    services.AddMvc();

         // register an IHttpContextAccessor so we can access the current
            // HttpContext in services by injecting it
            //---we use to this pull out the contents of the request

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

---

you want to inject this into whatever controller u are

### using to retrieve the json object of the POST request. Im going to use the example as Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        // make a read only field
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    //create ctor for controller and inject it
    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    // now in your post method use this to see what the if anything came in through the request:
    public async Task<IActionResult> Picload(IFormFile file){//---always null

    // in my problem I was loading and image from.
    var file =  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
}
```

Using this it gave me access to the image chrome was giving me an Origin error about.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working for me. I just changed my "startup.cs" file according to your solution. And its working.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me that somewhere in your C# code an error appear in time of execution and this way the "return" statement of the service is never executed. So debug your code and fix the error so the response is returned to the browser.